# Integrating with SAML in onelogin in ZEND project

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

SAML is quite new for me I don't know more about it. I'm trying to execute SAML demo on our local machine. but it through error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OneLogin_Saml2_Error' with message
>   'Invalid array settings: idp_entityId_not_found, idp_sso_not_found' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\saml\lib\Saml2\Settings.php:121 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\saml\lib\Saml2\Auth.php(107):
>   OneLogin_Saml2_Settings->__construct(Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\saml\demo1\index.php(13):
>   OneLogin_Saml2_Auth->__construct(Array) #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\saml\lib\Saml2\Settings.php on line 121

Setting files are like this:

```
 $spBaseUrl = 'http://localhost/saml'; //or http://<your_domain>

$settingsInfo = array (
    'sp' => array (
        'entityId' => $spBaseUrl.'/demo1/metadata.php',
        'assertionConsumerService' => array (
            'url' => $spBaseUrl.'/demo1/index.php?acs',
        ),
        'singleLogoutService' => array (
            'url' => $spBaseUrl.'/demo1/index.php?sls',
        ),
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',
    ),
    'idp' => array (
        'entityId' => '',
        'singleSignOnService' => array (
            'url' => '',
        ),
        'singleLogoutService' => array (
            'url' => '',
        ),
        'x509cert' => '',
    ),
);
```

I'm not sure what to put in the SP and IDP config file.
Please suggest instructions to execute it on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you review the error:
'Invalid array settings: idp_entityId_not_found, idp_sso_not_found'

you will get the reason why the Service Provider is not working.
you set the SP values, but you left blank the IdP data.

Ask to the IdP administrator for the IdP metadata XML in order to fill the IdP section of the settings array.